# How to decode a very large image on android?

Tags: android, image, performance, out-of-memory, decoding

I am decoding an image(ARGB) that is 8000x8000 pixels, so in uncompressed form it reaches
(2 + 2 + 2 + 2) * (8000 * 8000) = 488 MB
and crashes the android. I don't want to sample the image because I am converting the bitmap to byte array and sending it in a PUT request. I have tried "decodeRegion" but I don't know how to stitch the data(i.e. byte arrays) back together , since they have the head info at start and just concatenating them isn't helping.

Comment: yes, `BitmapRegionDecoder` is what you need call it several times top to bottom, but actually why do you want to send decoded data?

Comment: I have to put the image data into s3 as an image/png content type and I cannot change Amazon

Comment: image/png? so just send your png image without any decoding

Comment: I should have tried this before posting this question , my bad , but I'll try this , I don't know if it'll be able to parse it. Also how will I find the total size of file from the input stream ? (because content length has to be pre specified for this PUT request )

Comment: to parse what? where does your input stream come from?

Comment: Content Resolver

Comment: Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Use an HTTP client library that allows you to upload from a file or stream, so that you do not need to decode the image and try to hold it in memory. OkHttp has options for this; see [this recipe for streaming a POST request](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#post-streaming), [this recipe for POSTing a file](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#posting-a-file), or [this recipe for multipart POSTs](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#posting-a-multipart-request). Those techniques should be adaptable to a PUT request.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you reading in a large image, decoding it, then posting the byte array?  That's the wrong way to do it.
If your API actually requires the decoded bytes, fix it.  More likely it wants the file's raw data.  In which case you just need to use any networking API that gives you an `OutputStream`, and read in the file's data 1 MB at a time, reading it from the File's `InputStream` and writing it to the socket's `OutputStream`